# No module names xlrd

Tags: python, r

I am working out of R Studio and am trying to replicate what I am doing in R in Python. On my terminal, it is saying that I have xlrd already installed but when I try to import the package (import xlrd) in R Studio, it tells me: "No module named 'xlrd'". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this on my own. In your terminal, go to ls -a and this will list out applications on your laptop. If Renviron is there, type nano .Renviron to write to the Renviron file. Find where Python is stored on your laptop and type RETICULATE_PYTHON=(file path where Python is stored). ctrl + x to exit, y to save and then hit enter. Restart R studio and this should work for you.